# Объясните, как работает этот код (Python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class GameState(Enum):
   QUIT = -1
   TITLE = 0
   NEWGAME = 1

def main():
   pygame.init()

   screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_w, screen_h))
   game_state = GameState.TITLE

   while True:
      if game_state == GameState.TITLE:
          game_state = title_screen(screen)

      if game_state == GameState.NEWGAME:
          game_state = play_level(screen)

      if game_state == GameState.QUIT:
          pygame.quit()
          return
```

Меня интересует данная строка из функции **main()**:

```
if game_state == GameState.TITLE:
        game_state = title_screen(screen)
```

Проверяется условие, а потом выполняется присвоение переменной **game_state** функции **title_screen()**. Но дело в том, что переменная **game_state** больше нигде в коде не вызывается, только в цикле **while** и эта строчка

```
game_state = title_screen(screen)
```

срабатывает в коде так, как будто после проверки условия происходит не присвоение, а непосредственно вызов функции **title_screen()**, как будто если бы было просто

```
if game_state == GameState.TITLE:
        title_screen(screen)
```

Объясните, как это работает, почему вместо вызова функции используется присвоение переменной?
Вот полный код, если что: https://disk.yandex.ru/d/LFmmqnkNMIawgg

Comment: *>дело в том, что переменная game_state больше нигде в коде не вызывается, только в цикле while и эта строчка* - как же это? Вон же ещё 2 `if`'а, где смотрится этот `game_state`.

Comment: ну так я и написал - "только в цикле while" и больше нигде

Comment: вопрос то в чём, как происходит вызов функции title_screen() ? Ведь во всех if происходит проверка и присвоение, но срабатывает как будто это вызов функции, почему?

Comment: `Объясните, как это работает, почему вместо вызова функции используется присвоение переменной?` - не вместо, а вместе. Сначала вызов функции, потом результат вызова функции (то что функция вернула через return) записывается в переменную. А в следующих if проверяется значение этой переменной.